# Using LINQ to SQL for two different databases

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have a Router that saves changes from incoming messages to a database that is used by our CRM software. The Router uses LINQ to SQL for communication. We just released a completely revisioned version of the software that was built from the ground up, and runs on a different database.

Rather than maintaining two Routers with almost identical code, we want to change the code to work on either database, and change the context dynamically. This requires having a DataContext for each of the two formats.

My question is, can I have a DataContext for a database that doesn't exist on the system as long as the context is never used? I plan on refactoring all database communication to a single dll, and use two different classes that implement the same interface to access the two different databases. I will then only call methods in the correct class, but the dll would hold both DataContexts.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can... it doesn't try to connect until you create an instance and start querying.

Comment: @mellamokb: Thank you. That was what I suspected, but wanted to confirm.

Comment: A datacontext optionally accepts a connection string as input, you might not even need two context